# insert query with subqueries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, insert, subquery

I am trying to insert some values (CIID and AID) taken from another tables, but as not an expert, I couldn't manage to do it.

Insert query :

```
INSERT INTO INST_ACTIVE_ACTIONS act 
   (act.CIID, act.AID, act.STEPNUM, act.CREATEDATE) 
VALUES 
   (CIID , ,0,GETDATE())
```

The CIID Query is :

```
SELECT  C.CIID FROM INST_COURSE C 
LEFT JOIN INST_ACTIVE_ACTIONS AA ON (AA.CIID = C.CIID)
LEFT JOIN INST_TASKS T ON (T.CIID = C.CIID) 
LEFT JOIN SYS_SCH_ACTION SCH ON (SCH.CIID = C.CIID)
LEFT JOIN SYS_SUB_STACK SUB ON (SUB.RETURN_CIID=C.CIID)
WHERE C.COMPLETED IS NULL AND AA.AID IS NULL AND T.AID IS NULL AND SCH.AID IS NULL AND SUB.RETURN_AID IS NULL
```

AID Query is :

```
SELECT TOP 1 ca.AID 
FROM INST_COMPLETE_ACTIONS CA 
  INNER JOIN TMPL_ACT_MASTER TAM ON CA.AID=TAM.AID  
WHERE ca.CIID =c.CIID  ORDER BY TSTAMP DESC
```

> act.CIID = C.CIID = ca.CIID and CA.AID = act.AID

Edited :

the last query is

```
 INSERT INTO INST_ACTIVE_ACTIONS  (CIID,AID,stepnum,CREATEDATE
            )

            VALUES

       (
                 (SELECT    c.CIID
                 FROM      INST_COURSE  C
                 LEFT JOIN INST_ACTIVE_ACTIONS AA
                 ON        (
                                     aa.CIID = c.CIID)
                 LEFT JOIN INST_TASKS T
                 ON        (
                                     t.CIID = c.CIID)
                 LEFT JOIN SYS_SCH_ACTION SCH
                 ON        (
                                     sch.CIID = c.CIID)
                 LEFT JOIN sys_sub_stack SUB
                 ON        (
                                     sub.RETURN_CIID = c.CIID)
                 WHERE     c.completed IS NULL
                 AND       aa.AID IS NULL
                 AND       t.AID IS NULL
                 AND       sch.AID IS NULL
                 AND       sub.return_AID IS NULL),
       (
                  SELECT TOP 1
                             ca.AID
                  FROM       INST_COMPLETE_ACTIONS CA
                  INNER JOIN tmpl_act_master TAM
                  ON         ca.AID=tam.AID

                  ORDER BY   tstamp DESC 
                  ),
       0,
       Getdate() )
```

but i get an error as

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,
>
> > , >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL 2012 @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: If you're going to do this `ca.CIID =c.CIID` you need to put the queries together.

Comment: @Edward thanks, that's what i want to do, i want to merge all these three queries in one...

Comment: noone has (except @Edward) interested yet...

Comment: So your first subquery must be the one returning multiple rows for the value c.CIID. You will need to clean it up with a group by or a TOP 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just condensed though its real busy if you ask me.

```
INSERT INTO INST_ACTIVE_ACTIONS  
(CIID, AID, STEPNUM, CREATEDATE) 
--OUTPUT INSERTED.* --if you want to see what was inserted uncomment this 
(SELECT  C.CIID,
    (SELECT TOP 1 CA.AID 
        FROM INST_COMPLETE_ACTIONS CA 
        INNER JOIN TMPL_ACT_MASTER TAM ON CA.AID=TAM.AID  
        WHERE CA.CIID =C.CIID  ORDER BY TSTAMP DESC)
        , 0,GETDATE())
FROM INST_COURSE C 
LEFT JOIN INST_ACTIVE_ACTIONS AA ON (AA.CIID = C.CIID)
LEFT JOIN INST_TASKS T ON (T.CIID = C.CIID) 
LEFT JOIN SYS_SCH_ACTION SCH ON (SCH.CIID = C.CIID)
LEFT JOIN SYS_SUB_STACK SUB ON (SUB.RETURN_CIID=C.CIID)
WHERE C.COMPLETED IS NULL AND AA.AID IS NULL AND T.AID IS NULL AND SCH.AID IS NULL AND SUB.RETURN_AID IS NULL)
```

Revised. tested, and working on my end. I still think if you have control on these tables you might look into the concept of Normalizing your database tables.

Comment: thanks for the care , but the first select has an error.... 

`Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
`

Comment: sometimes it just requires adding aliases. I will redo it. otherwise I need to create a similar setup to actually test my code.

Comment: @UmutK I tested a simplified version using temp tables and was able to revise my original code to get it working without any errors. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: i got an error `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
`

Comment: That, after looking, is because there is 2 `))` after the getdate. So the From isn't connected to the first Select like it should be. Remove one of those and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

You can always perform something like this, and use as many sub queries as needed. Make sure that the types are matching on both sides.

> ```
> Insert into table1 (value1, value2) Select val1,val2 from table2 ...
> ```

**edit**

> INSERT INTO INST_ACTIVE_ACTIONS act     (act.CIID, act.AID,
>   act.STEPNUM, act.CREATEDATE)  Select
>         (SELECT  C.CIID FROM INST_COURSE C  LEFT JOIN INST_ACTIVE_ACTIONS AA ON (AA.CIID = C.CIID) LEFT JOIN INST_TASKS T ON
>   (T.CIID = C.CIID)  LEFT JOIN SYS_SCH_ACTION SCH ON (SCH.CIID = C.CIID)
>   LEFT JOIN SYS_SUB_STACK SUB ON (SUB.RETURN_CIID=C.CIID) WHERE
>   C.COMPLETED IS NULL AND AA.AID IS NULL AND T.AID IS NULL AND SCH.AID
>   IS NULL AND SUB.RETURN_AID IS NULL), (SELECT TOP 1 ca.AID  FROM
>   INST_COMPLETE_ACTIONS CA    INNER JOIN TMPL_ACT_MASTER TAM ON
>   CA.AID=TAM.AID   WHERE ca.CIID =c.CIID  ORDER BY TSTAMP DESC act.CIID
>   = C.CIID = ca.CIID and CA.AID ),0,GETDATE()

Comment: i am not that experienced )))

Comment: the last part is weird... 

`WHERE      ca.ciid =c.ciid
                  ORDER BY   tstamp DESC act.ciid = c.ciid = ca.ciid
                  AND        ca.aid ),`

Comment: `WHERE      ca.CIID =c.CIID`   "c" also not recognized... i guess we need joins there as well...

Comment: This is what you provided, first, run both of your queries separately and make sure they are working.

Comment: `INSERT INTO` does not work without `VALUES` and you are right, there is no `c.CIID` )))